# Почему в файл не записывается текст?

Tags: c#

```
                            string FileUserLogin = "C:/Crypit/save/User.txt";
                        string FileUserPass = "C:/Crypit/save/passworld.txt";

                        FileInfo fileInf = new FileInfo(FileUserLogin);
                        FileInfo fileInf1 = new FileInfo(FileUserPass);

                        string[] users = new string[] { "Login: " + textBox1.Text };
                        string[] pass = new string[] { "Passworld: " + textBox2.Text };

                        if (fileInf.Exists == false)
                        {
                            File.Create(FileUserLogin);
                            File.WriteAllLines("User.txt", users);
                        }
```

вот код но почему то у меня файл создается но текст не записывается

Comment: так может во WriteAllLines передать первым параметром FileUserLogin?

Comment: Вы создаете один пустой файл `File.Create(FileUserLogin);`, а пишите в другой файл `File.WriteAllLines("User.txt", users);`

Comment: да это работает, но не подскажите как теперь избавиться от ошибки "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу" я так предпологаю что файл не успевает создаться как вызывается запись в него

Answer (score 1):

1) Метод WriteAllLines уже создает файл, вам не нужно его создавать перед этим.

2) В метод WriteAllLines вы передаете название файла без пути к файлу. Такой файл будет создан в директории вашего проекта в bin\Debug\{version}\ или bin\Release\{version}\
Поищите этот файл там, он открывается без проблем.

Либо выберете тот файл, который вам нужен в WriteAllLines:

```
var FileUserLogin = "C:/Crypt/save/User.txt";
var FileUserPass = "C:/Crypt/save/password.txt";

var fileUserLoginFileInfo = new FileInfo(FileUserLogin);
var fileUserPassFileInfo = new FileInfo(FileUserPass);

var users = new [] { "Login: " + textBox1.Text };
var pass = new [] { "Password: " + textBox2.Text };

if (fileUserLoginFileInfo.Exists == false)
{
   File.WriteAllLines(fileUserLoginFileInfo.FullName, users);
}
```